# Sorting on List using Comparator in Java

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have two class

```
public class PopularSports {    
    public int Rank;    
    public String Sport;
}

public class Medals {
    public String Sport    
    public String Medal    
    public int Year    
    public String Game    
    public String Athlete
}
```

When i try to lead their csv and get the result in List of each class, I want to sort them in following order.

The PopularSports class should sort in the following order:

1. Rank
2. Sport

The Medals class should sort in the following order:

1. Sport
2. Medal
3. Year
4. Game
5. Athlete

I have created compactor like this

```
Collections.sort(medalReportList, new Comparator<Medals >() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Medals o1, Medals o2) {
   return getRankOfSportBySportName(o1.getSport()) > getRankOfSportBySportName(o2.getSport())
          ? +1
          : getRankOfSportBySportName(o1.getSport()) < getRankOfSportBySportName(o2.getSport())
          ? -1
          : o1.getAthlete().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getAthlete());
    }
  });
```

But it is not making it happen, it sorts on athlete names.

Comment: Ok hope you dont have problem in sorting first list?? How do u want to sort second....?? i.e if sport is same then sort according to medal and if medal is same sort according to game etc ...and so on?? is that u want??

Comment: Please include some data you want to sort.

Comment: What does your `getRankOfSportBySportName` return? Are you sure it works correctly?

Comment: @Jesper that functions returns the int rank of sport

Comment: @jesper Thanks for it, yes that function was behaving odd as csv reading was taking " as well while reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to nest those checks.  I'll write the PopularSports method and leave the other for you.

I'd recommend that you learn that Java coding standards and make those class names singular: `PopularSport` and `Medal`.  I'll demonstrate below:

```
public int compareTo(PopularSport other) {
    if (this.rank < other.rank) return -1;
    else if (this.rank > other.rank) return +1;
    else {
        // This is where the nesting happens to break the ties.
        if (this.sport.compareTo(other.sport) < 0) return -1;
        else if (this.sport.compareTo(other.sport) > 0) return +1;
        else return 0;  // You'll have deeper nesting for the other values in Medal.
    }
}
```

The order you choose determines which ones are checked first.  You nest in the `else` clause to break the ties.

Comment: Let me try this and come back to you

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify you logic a bit.

```
public int compare(Medals o1, Medals o2) {
  int rankDifference = getRankOfSportBySportName(o1.getSport()) 
                             - getRankOfSportBySportName(o2.getSport());
  return rankDifference != 0 
      ? rankDifference
      : o1.getAthlete().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getAthlete());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Others already gave you a solution with ternary operator. I, on the other hand, discourage you from using it in complicated situations - it's simply not readable and hard to maintain.

Either go with if/else blocks (which will look pretty bad with so many fields to compare) or, even better, use a third party library. In [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) you can use [ComparisionChain](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html) like this:

```
new Comparator<Medals>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Medals m1, Medals m1) {
        return ComparisonChain.start()
         .compare(m1.getSport(), m2.getSport())
         .compare(m1.getMedal(), m2.getMedal())
         .compare(m1.getYear(), m2.getYear())
         .compare(m1.getGame(), m2.getGame())
         .compare(m1.getAthlete(), m2.getAthlete(), String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
         .result();
    }
}
```

Isn't that more readable?!

Answer (score -1):

Sorting first list will no problem to you. If you want to sort as if sportName is same then sort according to medal and if medal name is same then sort according to year then solution is :

Best way:

```
public void sortAccordingToAboveRequirement(List<Medal> medals){

 Collections.sort(medals,myComparator);

 }


  static Comparator<Medal> myComparator=new Comparator<Medal>() {
    @Override
        public int compare(Medal medal1, Medal medal2) {
        int value=0;
        value=medal1.getSport().compareTo(medal2.getSport());
        if(value!=0) return value;
        value=medal1.getMedal().compareTo(medal2.getMedal());
        if(value!=0) return value;
        value=medal1.getYear().compareTo(medal2.getYear());
        if(value!=0) return value;
        value=medal1.getGame().compareTo(medal2.getGame());
        if(value!=0) return value;
        value=medal1.getAthlete().compareTo(medal2.Athlete());
        return value;
    }
};
```

Use compareToIgnoreCase() if you wish :)

Comment: Hehehe i took it wrong way your question but very poor way of coding and questioning :(